# Not able to load or apply external CSS file in Sharepoint 2019 on premises

Tags: html, jquery, css, sharepoint, spfx

[web-part without custom CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niwyz.png)

[Web-Part with inline CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCSfQ.png)

[Custom.css file is loaded but not apllied in web-part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypw07.png)

It works fine if we add inline css. The CSS file is loaded without any errors yet the CSS is not applied.

Comment: Could you please share your css and what part is not applied?

Comment: body {background-color: black;  padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%;}
a{ color: white!important; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none; }

this is the CSS but it is not applied in web-part. I have shared the Screen Shot for the same. the Custom css file is loaded but css is not applied

Comment: Thank you and how did you load those css into modern page?

Comment: I have loaded CSS using Component Loader into modern page. same thing applying to classic page but not working. only CSS file is being loaded but CSS is not appied on pages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check against the elements tab in Chrome?  Make sure there isn't a default style overriding the custom css.  Depending on the load order, it might have styles overriding your custom styles.  It will also show if your styles are loading to the elements.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked there is nothing which overrides my custom css.